# How to call Operator "" on variable

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

So I have defined this operator:

```
constexpr double operator"" _deg(double deg)
{
    return deg * M_PI / 180.0L;
}
```

So far so good. On constants I can now just write:

```
90.0_deg
```

But what if we have defined a double and whant to convert it:

```
double foo = 3.14
```

How do you call the operator on foo?

I tried:

```
_deg(foo)
```

but it says foo is not defined.

Also

```
operator""(foo)
```

does obviously not work.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can explicitly invoke the user-defined-literal (UDL) like this:

```
operator""_deg(foo);
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/95EdxY).

Note that `double` is not a valid argument type for a UDL. You can change it to `long double` instead.